# Android unzip file EOFException

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm getting following error:

```
03-17 02:10:13.272: W/System.err(26433): java.io.EOFException
03-17 02:10:13.282: W/System.err(26433):    at     libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
03-17 02:10:13.282: W/System.err(26433):    at     java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:231)
```

i run an download on a background thread 
the permission to write to external storage is set.
my code is:

```
ZipInputStream zis = null;
try
{
    zis = new ZipInputStream(archive);
    ZipEntry zeCurrent;
    while ((zeCurrent = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {
       [...]
    }
}
```

the loop is called 0 times because this eof is called before it can go into the loop.
what's going on there?

i use restlet for json communication.
my download code:

```
ClientResource cres = new ClientResource(myURL);
cres.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
Representation response = request.post(new JacksonRepresentation<MyRequest>(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, request));

unzip(response.getStream(), downloadPath);
```

so, MyRequest ist my Object which represents the json, the downloadPath exists.

Comment: where do you initialize `archive`?

Comment: Post your download code. I virtually guarantee your write code isn't doing Java streams correctly, assuming your unzip code and archive reference are correct ;)